# Upgraded to .NET 4.5 and EF5. No longer able to deploy WCF Service.

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, entity-framework, .net-4.5

We have a wcf service that runs as an application in a separate application pool on our webserver in a subfolder. We upgraded to .NET 4.5 in Dec. and EF5 in January. We did our standard web deploy yesterday which does not touch this code, and the WCF service stopped working.

We can move the old code to a different production server and it works. When using the old code on the production site we get a code produced error that indicate connectivity issues to the database (Unable to LogIn).

We tried deploying the WCF with upgraded 4.5 and EF5, but get runtime errors: "The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception." We have done all the config changes indicated, such as defaultConnectionFactory, for EF5. When doing so, the WCF starts giving a 301 redirection to the service endpoint when calling any service method. We are stumped as why a normal web deploy would cause these issues, and why we can't deploy upgraded EF versions to get us out of this hole.

This is a live and very active service used by our business partners.

Comment: Not related to answer but if you are upgrading EF why not upgrade to latest version 6.02

Comment: I find myself unable to understand Your description. What does December and January have to do with anything? If Your web deploy do not touch WCF service then what did You deploy? If You deployed some other app then what did You upgrade? WCF Service or that App? It's all very confusing to me.

Comment: We have previously upgraded website .net and EF. We did a simple deploy that did update some edmx's, but nothing that should touch this service. The service was isolated in it's own application and virtual directory. However, it stopped. The service should, theoretically, be able to stay in whatever version of EF and .NET we want, so long as the data structure doesn't change. We don't think the underlying data structure that the service uses changed, as we can move it to a different server and it works. Hoping it was just a weird GAC or IIS issue, we thought it best to recompile as 4.5 and EF5

Comment: However, we can't get the 4.5/EF4 version of the service to deploy, giving us the above errors.

Comment: SO, .NET 4.5/EF4 works fine in dev or/and test environments? What does the event log say?

Comment: Can you post your web.config file for the service?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Event log says nothing. It looked to be a binding issue between IIS and the interface. Turned out to be conflicting web.config's keeping the IIS from loading the web.config fully/causing duplicate entries. The only config item that caused the break was an EntityFramework connect string. We run EF5.0 on .NET 4.5. Here is the offending connection string:

String in root Web.Config:

```
<add name="MyConfigurationEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyConfigurationModel.csdl|res://*/MyConfigurationModel.ssdl|res://*/MyConfigurationModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=SERVER1;Initial Catalog=MyConfiguration;User ID=sa;Password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

String in web service Web.Config:

```
<add name="MyConfigurationEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyConfigurationModel.csdl|res://*/MyConfigurationModel.ssdl|res://*/MyConfigurationModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=Server1;Initial Catalog=MyConfiguration;User ID=sa;Password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Our folder structure is:

/web.config

/webservices/webservice/web.config